# limiting google maps autocomplete to 50 MILES from the location given address only

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

i have go through the example from the link below
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1

i tried with the example but am not getting the expected output the address is going out of the range what i have mentioned radius ,below i have added my code of the autocomplete please suggest me what i went wrong

```
var center22 = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: 51.448386, lng: -0.199501 });
    service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();


    service.getPlacePredictions({
        input: query, location: center22, radius: 50000, strictbounds: true, componentRestrictions: { country: 'GB' }

    }, function (predictions, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {               
            dfd.resolve([]);


        }       


            dfd.resolve(predictions);
            return dfd.promise

        }
    });
```

Comment: I get a syntax error with your code (`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip , while adding the code into it its has missed closing braces at last but one currely braces,am using this code by changing it., but the address is going beyond the radius limit ., please give me the suggestion

Comment: It is still not a [mcve]. That was only a symptom of the fact that you hadn't tested the code you posted to verify it exhibited the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Strict bounds are not implemented for the AutocompleteService yet. Currently you can only bias results to certain area, but not restrict.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker for this:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219203

Feel free to star this feature request to express your interest and subscribe to notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  zoom.
You can set the zoom size when you initialize the map。

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    map.setZoom(12);
```

Comment: my question is about the limiting autocomplete place prediction of search address ,not the zooming of the map ,anyway thanks for your replay